# Can't select Ubuntu menu categories to show

Tags: 10.04, alacarte

When I tick a checkbox to show Ubuntu 10.04 menu category, the checkbox unticks itself after a couple of seconds. [Gif of screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3ROX.gif).
Is there any other way to edit Ubuntu menu categories or add a category? LXMenuEditor doesn't work on my system (I get `Unable to access jarfile /opt/lxmed/LXMenuEditor.jar` when trying to launch it, probably because it requires Sun's JRE).
I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 for PPC.

Comment: have you tried menulibre?

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution, you have to create and check an item in a menu/category for it to be shown.